# Add png image in pdf with nodejs and jspdf

Tags: node.js, jspdf

I am pretty new to `nodeJs` and I am trying create a pdf with `jsPdf` on server.

I have installed the jspdf using `npm install jspdf --save`

As nodeJs doest have support for `atob` which was used in jspdf, I have added

`npm install atob --save`   and added

```
var atob = require('atob');
var PNG = require('png-js');
```

where `png-js` is required for adding png files in `jspdf`. 
When I try to add the PNG file to the pdf with following code

```
let imgData=request.payload.canvasobj;
let pdfContent = new jsPDF();
pdfContent.addImage(imgData, 'PNG',  40, 20, 0, 0);
let data = pdfContent.output('arraybuffer');
let buffer = Buffer.from(data);
let arraybuffer = Uint8Array.from(buffer);
fs.appendFile('./canvas.pdf', new Buffer(arraybuffer), function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("PDF created");
    }
});
```

the following error is triggered

```
Debug: internal, implementation, error
    TypeError: Uncaught error: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined
    at Object.jsPDFAPI.processPNG (C:\LearningPro\NodeJsProjects\pdfexport-nodejs\node_modules\jspdf\dist\jspdf.debug.js:8796:80)
    at Object.jsPDFAPI.addImage (C:\LearningPro\NodeJsProjects\pdfexport-nodejs\node_modules\jspdf\dist\jspdf.debug.js:4696:50)
    at canvas (C:\LearningPro\NodeJsProjects\pdfexport-nodejs\requestHandler.js:105:16)
    at Object.internals.handler (C:\LearningPro\NodeJsProjects\pdfexport-nodejs\node_modules\hapi\lib\handler.js:99:36)
    at request._protect.run (C:\LearningPro\NodeJsProjects\pdfexport-nodejs\node_modules\hapi\lib\handler.js:30:23)
    at internals.Protect.run (C:\LearningPro\NodeJsProjects\pdfexport-nodejs\node_modules\hapi\lib\protect.js:59:12)
    at exports.execute (C:\LearningPro\NodeJsProjects\pdfexport-nodejs\node_modules\hapi\lib\handler.js:24:22)
    at each (C:\LearningPro\NodeJsProjects\pdfexport-nodejs\node_modules\hapi\lib\request.js:382:16)
    at iterate (C:\LearningPro\NodeJsProjects\pdfexport-nodejs\node_modules\hapi\node_modules\items\lib\index.js:36:13)
    at done (C:\LearningPro\NodeJsProjects\pdfexport-nodejs\node_modules\hapi\node_modules\items\lib\index.js:28:25)
Debug: internal, implementation, error
    TypeError: fn is not a function
    at C:\LearningPro\NodeJsProjects\pdfexport-nodejs\node_modules\png-js\png-node.js:246:16
    at Inflate.onEnd (zlib.js:227:5)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Inflate.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

What do I am missing out? It works fine with JPEG Image.

image data from log

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA...QmCC
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var path_url = '/usr/logo.png', format = 'PNG';    
//format 'JPEG', 'PNG', 'WEBP'    
var imgData = fs.readFileSync(path_url).toString('base64');    
var doc = new jsPDF();    
doc.addImage(imgData, format, 0, 0, 5, 1)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on [edit] and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/26983653)

Answer (score 4):

Having worked with the jsPDF library and stumbled upon errors with having the invalid imageData input format, I advise you to add logging to determine the format of imageData as follows:

```
let imgData=request.payload.canvasobj;
console.log(imgData);
```

Ensure that the format is:

```
data:image/png;base64,...
```

Where ... is your image data encoded in base64.

**EDIT**
I set up jsPDF locally. In order to get the jspdf package (from npm) working in Node.JS 4.x, I had to do the following:

```
global.PNG = require('png-js');
global.window = {document: {createElementNS: () => {return {}} }};
global.navigator = {};
global.atob = require('atob');
```

Then went on to create the jsPDF object successfully.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var jsPDF = require('jspdf');
var imgData = fs.readFileSync('imgdata').toString();
var pdfContent = new jsPDF();
var ret = pdfContent.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 40, 20, 0, 0);
var data = new Buffer(pdfContent.output('arraybuffer'));

fs.appendFile('./canvas.pdf', data, function (err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log("PDF created");
    }
});
```

I assume I was not able to replicate your original issue because the setup required some tweaks in non-browser environments.

Comment: Image data is perfect I have added glimpse of the image data in question

Comment: I have updated my answer, have got an example working myself, having to create some global variables for the library to use. Please see.

Comment: stock `png-js` doesn't work perfectly with `jspdf`. I have modified the `png-js` from `png.js` provided with `jspdf`. Also for document i used `jsdom` as i needed more dom functionalities in my application.